# How to copy an image from one spreadsheet to another in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have added an image into a cell of a Google Sheet,
I'm trying to copy-paste it in the cell of a new spreadsheet but doing `CTRL+C` / `CTRL+V` doesn't work.

I've added the image doing: **Insert > Image > Image in cell**

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround to bring images from a spreadsheet to another here.
In this way, I can copy them to all the sheets of the new one.

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/copy-image-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet/.

Steps:

1. Insert a new tab in “File 1”. Let me call it “Sheet2”.
2. Click on the image that you want to copy on “Sheet1”. The image can be a floating image or in-cell image (inserted via Insert menu or Image function). But it doesn’t matter.
3. Ctrl+C to copy the image.
4. Go to “Sheet2” in the same file (“File 1”) and paste it using Ctrl+V.
5. Right-click the tab name on “Sheet2” and choose Copy to > Existing spreadsheet.
6. Select “File2”. You will be greeted with the message “Sheet copied
   successfully”.

Your image is now available in “File 2”.

If you have any solution that works better I would prefer rather then the workaround.